# "we need to ( examine/detect/investigate/detect/observe) how an accident like this can be avoided in the future " which one is it?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, sentence

I was solving exercises and this question came up, my teacher said that the answer was examine but another teacher said that it's actually detect, what is the answer?

Answer (score 1):

All of these words are verbs and all could fit grammatically.  This isn't a grammar question.

In terms of meaning, "examine" and "investigate" imply similar actions: observe carefully and critically in a attempt to discover something.  Either could be used. "Observe" is more passive and to discover how an accident can be prevented the more dynamic actions implied by "examine" are better.

"Detect" doesn't work for me.  I think your teacher thinks that "detect" means "to act like a detective".  But for me it doesn't have the sense of "investigate".  It has the sense of "uncover" or "pick up a weak signal", or more broadly "find".  This doesn't fit.  There may be nothing to find; there may be no way to avoid such accidents. "Detect" carries the wrong connotation.

So my answer would be "examine" or "investigate". Either of those would be "correct".

Comment: Agreed. You can detect how the accident happened, but you can't detect how to avoid another one.